# ForEach Loop Container connundrum

Tags: ssis

I have multiple .csv files in a dir.

I've created a ForEach Loop container that will cycle through each file in the dir.

[image]

The issue is I have an insert csv into database, and the target database table is defined by a SSIS var tblName which is null until the foreach container starts and fills the var CurrentFile with a filepath string.
[image]
The issue arises because this var isn't declared so the OLDBC connection wont work as it looks for a table with a null title.
[image]
is there any way to force the for each loop to start before establishing the connection with the database?

Comment: Are importing the contents of each CSV file into the same database table, or are you trying to import each CSV file into multiple database tables with each having a similar name to that of the source CSV file?

Comment: You could also trying dynamically changing the Connection String value of the OLE DB Connection Manager with each pass of the loop.  That is, first define an actual value for the tblName variable other than NULL.  Then apply that in an Expression of the ConnectionSring under your Connection Manager.  In the Expression you would replace the Catalog value with the tblName variable.  This way the catalog table name of the Connection Manager dynamically changes as the value for tblName changes with each pass of the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try ValidateExternal Meta data option false if you are loading into single table